# Some emojis are black and white in Anki (qt programme) instead of colored like in other applications

Tags: fonts, qt

Both programmes are configured to use the Roboto font. (Code uses Roboto Mono - but I've checked with Roboto Regular as well)

If it's helpful, in Firefox some look right, like the exclamation mark, and others don't, like the normal red heart.

What kind of problem is this? How could I correct this?

Thanks
[image: example of problematic emojis]

As a counter, here are some emojis that are displayed correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## All right!

After searching around, stumbling upon Twitter Color Emoji (spoiler: doesn't work on Linux - only for Firefox: https://github.com/eosrei/twemoji-color-font/issues/10#issuecomment-242988370 )

...and a bit of stumbling around, I found the solution on reddit: [How to better enable Color Emojis!](https://old.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/9q8dlj/how_to_better_enable_color_emojis/)

#### Here it goes!

1. Create a 75-noto-color-emoji.conf file in /etc/fonts/conf.avail/ with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>

    <!-- Add generic family. -->
    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family"><string>emoji</string></test>
        <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same"><string>Noto Color Emoji</string></edit>
    </match>

    <!-- This adds Noto Color Emoji as a final fallback font for the default font families. -->
    <match target="pattern">
        <test name="family"><string>sans</string></test>
        <edit name="family" mode="append"><string>Noto Color Emoji</string></edit>
    </match>

    <match target="pattern">
        <test name="family"><string>serif</string></test>
        <edit name="family" mode="append"><string>Noto Color Emoji</string></edit>
    </match>

    <match target="pattern">
        <test name="family"><string>sans-serif</string></test>
        <edit name="family" mode="append"><string>Noto Color Emoji</string></edit>
    </match>

    <match target="pattern">
        <test name="family"><string>monospace</string></test>
        <edit name="family" mode="append"><string>Noto Color Emoji</string></edit>
    </match>

    <!-- Block Symbola from the list of fallback fonts. -->
    <selectfont>
        <rejectfont>
            <pattern>
                <patelt name="family">
                    <string>Symbola</string>
                </patelt>
            </pattern>
        </rejectfont>
    </selectfont>

    <!-- Use Noto Color Emoji when other popular fonts are being specifically requested. -->
    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family"><string>Apple Color Emoji</string></test>
        <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same"><string>Noto Color Emoji</string></edit>
    </match>

    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family"><string>Segoe UI Emoji</string></test>
        <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same"><string>Noto Color Emoji</string></edit>
    </match>

    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family"><string>Segoe UI Symbol</string></test>
        <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same"><string>Noto Color Emoji</string></edit>
    </match>

    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family"><string>Android Emoji</string></test>
        <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same"><string>Noto Color Emoji</string></edit>
    </match>

    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family"><string>Twitter Color Emoji</string></test>
        <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same"><string>Noto Color Emoji</string></edit>
    </match>

    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family"><string>Twemoji</string></test>
        <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same"><string>Noto Color Emoji</string></edit>
    </match>

    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family"><string>Twemoji Mozilla</string></test>
        <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same"><string>Noto Color Emoji</string></edit>
    </match>

    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family"><string>TwemojiMozilla</string></test>
        <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same"><string>Noto Color Emoji</string></edit>
    </match>

    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family"><string>EmojiTwo</string></test>
        <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same"><string>Noto Color Emoji</string></edit>
    </match>

    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family"><string>Emoji Two</string></test>
        <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same"><string>Noto Color Emoji</string></edit>
    </match>

    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family"><string>EmojiSymbols</string></test>
        <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same"><string>Noto Color Emoji</string></edit>
    </match>

    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family"><string>Symbola</string></test>
        <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same"><string>Noto Color Emoji</string></edit>
    </match>

</fontconfig>
```

2. Now enable above by issuing the following:

`sudo ln -sf /etc/fonts/conf.avail/75-noto-color-emoji.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/`

## Ta da!

- Still on Firefox some emojis will remain black and white. Install Twitter Color Emoji for that: https://github.com/eosrei/twemoji-color-font

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to do but some programs prefer the so called symbolic images and if the emogies you use have a symbolic version - then they will use the symbolic one. If there is not - they use the colored one. Both versions correspond to one and the same string and no matter how they look in your screen, every application will use the style that the developpers of the app implemented so there is no correct and not correct - they are the same text information but any app will draws it by the way it is programmed to do that.